# Factorial program using assembly language whereby user need to enter an integer. However, i got illegal instruction

Tags: assembly, arm

```
.data
prompt: .asciz "Enter a positive integer number abc: "
scanformat: .asciz "%d"
product: .word 1
message: .asciz "Result: %d\n"


.global main                @ start of the assembly code

main:
 
    MOV R0, #0
    MOV R1, #1
    MOV R2, #0
    B input
    B calculate
    B output


input:
    
    B displayPrompt
    LDR R0, addr_format
    B scanf

    

displayPrompt:

    LDR R0, =prompt
    B printf


calculate:
    
    CMP R0, R2;
    BGT END
    MOV R5, #1
    MUL R1, R1, R5
    ADD R0, R0, #1
    B calculate

END:    

output:

    LDR R3, addr_message
    LDR R4, addr_product
    LDR R1, [R4]

    B printf



addr_format: .word scanformat
addr_product: .word product
addr_message: .word message
```

Comment: Don't you want `BL` instead of `B` if you're calling a subroutine?  Don't you want your subroutines to eventually return?    And don't you need to save the link register in order to achieve that?

Comment: Also, your `calculate` routine doesn't appear to do anything except multiply a number by `1` over and over again, which of course will never change it.

Comment: Illegal instruction where, at what address?  I'm surprised; your code tailcalls `input` (with a `b` instruction, leaving LR = main's return address as @Nate pointed out), which in turn tailcalls `displayPrompt`, which tailcalls `printf`.  So when printf eventually returns, it should be returning to main's caller.  Maybe immediate problem is Thumb vs. ARM mode; `b` doesn't do thumb interworking.  If you build this as ARM, and libc is compiled for Thumb2, `b` to printf would try to decode that Thumb2 code as ARM instructions, which could easily be illegal. `bx printf` might make it cleanly exit

Comment: But if you want to actually be able to return to `main`, yes as Nate said you need major changes.  Look at C compiler output (https://godbolt.org/ with `-mcpu=cortex-a15` or something) for an example of saving the incoming LR so you can return to it later.

Comment: @PeterCordes I assume you meant blx printf as you cant bx printf.

Comment: @old_timer: No, I did mean branch with interchange but without linking, to tailcall printf like it's currently doing.  Didn't realize that a direct relative-branch form of that instruction wasn't available, so I guess to do a tailcall you'd need to load the address into a register.  If you did `blx` from there, you'd destroy `main`'s return address because still nothing has saved it anywhere.  I was just trying to make something that would run without faulting, not that would actually work, because that's a much larger amount of fixing, given the total lack of return-address handlign.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, my point was you cant bx to a label has to be a register so yes ldr r3,=printf ; bx r3 or something.

Comment: @old_timer: Right, I understood that; thanks for catching the impossible instruction.

Answer (score 2):

When asking a good question on a topic like this you need to clarify the instruction set.  ARM has multiple instruction sets that conform to the same or similar assembly language.  Is this thumb? Does it support thumb2 extensions? (possible based on one instruction used). Or is it for lack of a better term full sized ARM instructions?  Clearly it is somewhere between armv4t and armv7-a/armv7-m but not armv6-m.  Even when you clarify the chip and/or core, it is best with ARM questions like this to also provide a disassembly so we can see that it is really building the instructions you want or due to the nature of things the problem is specifically with the machine code and not necessarily program (due to command line options, etc).

Most if not all of this has already been covered in the comments.

You cannot start assembly language without a good assembly language reference.  The chip in question will state an arm core (cortex-m4, cortex-a7, etc).  And then you go to arms website to get the technical reference manual for that core, and in that it tells you the architecture (armv7-m, armv5t, etc).  And THAT is the key to find the document that contains the instruction set.

Then there is assembly language syntax which is specific to the tool not the instruction set.  This looks to be gnu assembler and not kiel or other ARM tools.  But a well written question would have also mentioned the tool and version.

```
arm-none-eabi-as --version
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.35
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or later.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
This assembler was configured for a target of `arm-none-eabi'.
```

You should know for basic assembly language level programming for any target function calls need to have a return method which is specific to the instruction set architecture.  Some use the stack, some use registers, some the stack for this is buried and untouchable some it is clearly visible.  In the case of ARM up to armv7 it is a register, r14 or the link register.  When you make a call (ideally bl or blx) those instructions modify r14 to provide a return address right after the function

```
bl this
bl that
bl the_other
```

such that these can be run in sequence like this, you have to be able to get back from bl this to be able to run bl that next in this function.

Being register not stack based though a nested call will also change r14

```
bl this  <--- sets r14 to the return value of the bl that instruction
bl that 
...
this:
bl something <--- this modifies lr so it can return to the bx lr instruction
bx lr        <--- this branches to the address in lr (this is a return)
```

the problem is that lr in this: no longer points at bl that it either points
at the bx lr or the something function modified it and it points somewhere
else.  So you have to preserve it.  Easiest to just let a compiler show you

```
unsigned int one ( unsigned int );
unsigned int two ( unsigned int );
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    unsigned int c;
    c=one(a);
    c+=two(b);
    return(c);
}

arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c -march=armv5t so.c -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e92d4070    push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
   4:   e1a05001    mov r5, r1
   8:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <one>
   c:   e1a04000    mov r4, r0
  10:   e1a00005    mov r0, r5
  14:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <two>
  18:   e0840000    add r0, r4, r0
  1c:   e8bd8070    pop {r4, r5, r6, pc}
```

This is unlinked so the bl instructions are not set for an offset yet, but the
disassembly shows the labels.

```
unsigned int two ( unsigned int );
unsigned int one ( unsigned int a )
{
    return(two(a)+1);
}
00000000 <one>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <two>
   8:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
   c:   e8bd8010    pop {r4, pc}
```

And there you see it.  The r4 is not used and confusing but this is for a 64 bit stack alignment you will see the compiler use different registers here r3 sometimes, r4 sometimes, not relevant.  lr the link register (a.k.a r14).

Let me start here:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c -march=armv4t one.c -o one.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d one.o

one.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <one>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <two>
   8:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
   c:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

Different target, slightly different instruction set features, same instruction set.

The function two is being called, this is basically a nested call so the return
address needs to be preserved and the most common way is push it on the stack

```
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
```

call the function this destroys the return address in lr to use lr to return from two

```
   4:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <two>
```

this pops the lr back off the stack so that we can return from this function (one)

```
   8:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
   c:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
```

this is the return instruction branch to the address in lr

```
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

ARM before armv8-a (the 64 bit one, completely different, incompatible, instruction set) all cores support thumb (well armv4t on which is the current arm company) some support the full sized instruction set and there are rules as to how to switch between instruction sets.  armv4t you could not use a pop you could only use bx so if for example one function is arm the other thumb how you interwork that is to use bx lr as a return instruction.  Later cores you can use a pop

```
   c:   e8bd8010    pop {r4, pc}
```

So the pc being in the pop is another form of return from subroutine.

Some people call this a leaf function, but then googling for this answer saw at least one try to argue it wasn't, doesn't matter, this function does not make another call, there is no nested call within this function.  So we don't need to save the link register upon return we just use it

```
unsigned int two ( unsigned int a )
{
    return(a+5);
}
00000000 <two>:
   0:   e2800005    add r0, r0, #5
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

The compilers must use a calling convention for their output to work at all, specifically with respect to passed parameters and a return address solution.  And all of this has to fit within the target instruction set.  But writing assembly language programs you are free to do whatever you want.  Until you call C functions and then you must conform to the calling convention for that C compiler used to compile the C code you are linking with.

So you could for your own code do this if you wanted:

```
main:
  b there
main_back:
  ...

there:
  ...
  b main_back
```

But there can only return to main, it is not really a function call.  If you want to use there: any other time then

```
main:
   bl there
   ...

there:
   ...
   bx lr
```

or

```
there:
   push {lr}
   ...
   pop {lr}
   bx lr
```

Use the latter when in doubt, later learn to optimize.

This code is built with an ISA knowledge so the linker will know that when calling external code like printf and scanf, but with the arm instruction sets pre aarch64 you will want to indicate a few more things.  Note that the assembly language (which is tool specific not target, you can have an infinite number of incompatible assembly languages sets for the same arm thumb ISA for example) includes not just the instruction syntax but labels and all other syntax as well.

Looking at what gcc creates:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c -save-temps -march=armv4t two.c -o two.o
```

or

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -S -march=armv4t two.c
```

Then look at two.s, there is a whole lot of syntax you really don't need, but the compiler goes overboard with it.  These are the two in question that you should consider if you want to make a function that can be called from outside this file

```
.global two
.type   two, %function
```

the .type line tells the tool that the two label is a function and not just any other label type it will otherwise assume it is not a function label so that when the linker resolves two it won't treat it special, for function labels with the arm instruction set you need to do this for global functions.  Note your homework so far doesn't have any of these, but understanding interworking may be relevant to your homework assignment.

Also note that for some reason they have an alternate form of this that only works for thumb mode (.thumb in the code or -mthumb on the command line)

```
.globl this
.thumb_func
this:
```

The first label the assembler finds after the .thumb_func syntax it will type as a function.

Because you appear to be using gnu assembler (you should have indicated this). The last many versions of the linker will take care of you:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c so.c -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c one.c -o one.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c -mthumb two.c -o two.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext=0x1000 so.o one.o two.o -o so.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d so.elf

Disassembly of section .text:

00001000 <fun>:
    1000:   e92d4070    push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
    1004:   e1a05001    mov r5, r1
    1008:   eb000005    bl  1024 <one>
    100c:   e1a04000    mov r4, r0
    1010:   e1a00005    mov r0, r5
    1014:   eb000009    bl  1040 <__two_from_arm>
    1018:   e0840000    add r0, r4, r0
    101c:   e8bd4070    pop {r4, r5, r6, lr}
    1020:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00001024 <one>:
    1024:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
    1028:   eb000004    bl  1040 <__two_from_arm>
    102c:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
    1030:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
    1034:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00001038 <two>:
    1038:   3005        adds    r0, #5
    103a:   4770        bx  lr
    103c:   0000        movs    r0, r0
    ...

00001040 <__two_from_arm>:
    1040:   e59fc000    ldr r12, [pc]   ; 1048 <__two_from_arm+0x8>
    1044:   e12fff1c    bx  r12
    1048:   00001039    .word   0x00001039
    104c:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
```

the linker creates a trampoline for us.  if your toolchain does not do that you might have to do something like this instead

```
ldr r3,=printf
blx r3
```

instead of

```
bl printf
```

Also understanding that

```
ldr r3,=printf
```

is a pseudo instruction and very much specific to the tool not the target as to if it is even valid and as to what it does.  For gnu assembler and some others that equals means address of load the address of printf into r3 and then blx r3 if supported (not on armv4t some cores) branch link to the address in a register.

And why 0x1039 and not 0x1038?  The lsbit is used for branching (it does NOT live in the PC that way) to indicate switch to arm or switch to thumb mode when doing a branch exchange or pop or other instruction that supports thumb interworking.  The lsbit being set indicates the destination label/address is thumb code.

Lastly you don't appear to have an end of program solution, even if you fix up all these issues, and don't return properly your program can/will still go off the rails.  But you are probably using a simulator for this?  Or some sandbox provided by the school for this class?  You need to refer to how to do a proper end of program based on that environment as there is arguably no generic solution that works everywhere, you could end main with a bx lr assuming you preserved lr.  Or a b exit or make the system call.

Comment: In user-space under an OS that provides a C environment with functions like `printf` and a `main` you define, it's almost certain you can exit by returning from `main`; it's just a function like any other.  No need to make a big deal out of main specifically, it's just the same bug as all the functions with a total lack of return-address handling.  But yes `blx exit` would mean you didn't need to save main's return address.  We already know a chain of tailcalls ending in `b printf` resulted in an illegal instruction, so `b exit` is unlikely to work.